Are there single and dual socket version of AMD EPYC 9754?
I need to build a dual cpu system with AMD EPYC-9754, and need to buy two CPUs of this type.
As we know, there are two different version of 9654, i.e. 9654P and 9654, where the former for single socket and the other for dual sockets respectively.
I can't search any information about 9754P. Is it meanning that there's no "P" version of 9754? If I buy two 9754s, and plug them into a same Gigabyte MZ73-LM1 motherboard, will they work?
Thanks!!!

There's no 9754P, only the 9754 for both single and dual sockets.
Check all EPYC specs on https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/server-processor.html.
I guess you've noticed the 9754 uses 4c cores, but just to make sure.
The Gigabyte MZ73-LM1 is for two 9004 CPUs, so that should work.
